# clang-format unrolls empty initializer

Tags: clang-format

I have a simple structure variable declaration: `struct sigaction act{};`.

`clang-format` (version 10.0) unrolls it into this:

```
struct sigaction act
    {
    };
```

I did set `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty`, but something is still missing. 
What else can be set to avoid this transformation? The `.clang-format` file is the following:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
BasedOnStyle:  Google
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true # false
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
AfterCaseLabel:  true
AfterClass:      true # false
AfterControlStatement: MultiLine # false
AfterEnum:       false
AfterFunction:   true # false
AfterNamespace:  true # false
AfterObjCDeclaration: true # false
AfterStruct:     true # false
AfterUnion:      true # false
AfterExternBlock: true # false
BeforeCatch:     true # false
BeforeElse:      true # false
IndentBraces:    true # false
SplitEmptyFunction: true
SplitEmptyRecord: true
SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman # Attach
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     120
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
- foreach
- Q_FOREACH
- BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:   4  #2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Middle # Right
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` option doesn't affect struct declarations, it affects while statements (see the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)). Maybe what you would want is something like "AllowShortStructsOnASingleLine", but that doesn't exist.

The root of your problem is `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman`. Changing that to `Attach` would fix your problem. But perhaps you like `Allman` in most cases. Then you could, instead, use `Custom`, like this:

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     false # <-- You need this
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: false # <-- And this
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom # <-- And this
```

The rest of the `BraceWrapping` settings can be left the way `BreakBeforeBreaces: Allman` would set them; only `AfterStruct` and `SplitEmptyRecord` affect your structure declaration.

Comment: I've tried you suggestion @Eric, but as soon as I set `BreakBeforeBraces` to `Custom`, the formatted now sets the `if` statements to look like `BreakBeforeBraces: Attach` or `BreakBeforeBraces: Linux`.

Comment: Try setting all of the `BraceWrapping` settings as listed above. If you don't change them, they may default to the LLVM settings, which would match `Attach`. But what I listed above should match `Allman` except for the two which changed to get the struct declaration on one line.

Comment: Works, thank you. Had to add `AfterCaseLabel` to be complete.